# Not locating a field for compile of RPG program

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400, rpg

I have an rpg program that is not compiling. the strange thing: it's missing some fields as stated in the output. 7030. But I dont' see these fields in the file it is supposed to reside on. I know this because I can compile the program in Production machine. One of these fields is CAMPAIGN. I am showing the output: So where does this CAMPAiGN field come from? I think its an alias name for CAMP_CODE but where does this show?

```
 Find  . . . . . .   CAMPAIGN                                                   
 *...+....1....+....2....+....3....+....4....+....5....+....6....+....7....+... 
   1443=O                       PROC_CODE          322A CHAR        8           
   1444=O                       CAMPAIGN           330A CHAR        8           
   1445=O                       IRPTCAT01          333A CHAR        3           
   1446=O                       IRPTCAT02          336A CHAR        3           
   1447=O                       IRPTCAT03          339A CHAR        3           
   1448=O                       IRPTCAT04          342A CHAR        3           

But it's not in the source:

CUSTOMER# CHAR ( 8),                      
NAME CHAR (40 ),                          
CITY CHAR (30 ),                          
STATE CHAR (3 ),                          
COUNTRY CHAR (3 ),                        
ZIP_CODE char (10 ),                      
ITEM# CHAR (15 ),                         
ITEM_TEXT CHAR (40 ),                     
ORDER# CHAR (8 ),                         
ORD_STATUS CHAR (2 ),                     
INVOICE# CHAR (8 ),                       
ORD_DATE NUMERIC (8 , 0),                 
INV_DATE numeric (8 , 0),                 
ORD_TYPE CHAR (3 ),                       
CUST_TYPE CHAR (3 ),                      
PROD_LINE CHAR (3 ),                      
SALES_REP CHAR (3 ),                      
WAREHOUSE CHAR (3 ),                        
SHIP_VIA CHAR (3 ),                         
TERRITORY CHAR (3 ),                        
HOLD_CODE CHAR (3 ),                        
HNDL_CODE CHAR (3 ),                        
EXTENDED$ numeric (11 , 4),                 
QUANTITY NUMERIC (7 , 0),                   
ZONE CHAR (1 ),                             
ITEM_PRC$ NUMERIC (11 , 4),                 
ITEM_COST$ NUMERIC (11 , 4),                
ORD_SHIP$ NUMERIC (7 , 2),                  
ORD_WT NUMERIC (7 , 4),                     
TRANS_DAYS CHAR (1 ),                       
KEYCODE CHAR (8 ),                          
PROC_CODE CHAR (8 ),                        
CAMP_CODE CHAR (8 ),                        
ORD_HLDC CHAR (3 ),                         
Irptcat01 char (3 ),                                                 
Irptcat02 char (3 ),                                                 
Irptcat03 char (3 ),                                                 
Irptcat04 char (3 ),                                                 
Irptcat05 char (3 ),                                                 
Irptcat06 char (3 ),                                                 
Irptcat07 char (3 ),                                                 
Irptcat08 char (3 ),                                                 
Irptcat09 char (3 ),                                                 
Irptcat10 char (3 ),                                                 
Irptcat11 char (3 ),                                                 
Irptcat12 char (3 ),                                                 
Irptcat13 char (3 ),                                                 
Irptcat14 char (3 ),                                                 
Irptcat15 char (3 )                                                  
NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT)                                               
Table DTAWHS in PROJ_N1 created but was not journaled.
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "it's not in the source". What "source" are you looking at? It doesn't seem like you should be looking at any "source" for the table, but maybe you mean that you're looking at "generated source" from the live table rather than any original source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another very common cause for these errors is the library list.  If your compilation is using a different library list to the production library list, you may be referring to the wrong file.  Check the compiler listing to see exactly which library was used for the file definition.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the source code for the table (file) is not going to help you, as the table could have been changed after creation. You should inspect the actual table/file object.

**CL Commands:**

**DSPFFD** : Information regarding the Fields, currently in the table/file. Is CAMPAIGN defined, on Dev?

**DSPFD** : To confirm that the "Live" table's structure is the same as "Dev", the File level identifier (Level ID) for the tables needs to be the same.